# start pythonenvironment using shell scrapit and execute command

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, virtualenv

I have `ubuntu` server , and my python virtualenv is under `/var/www/abc/python` folder.

and my code is under `/var/www/abc/code` folder.

Now i want to start virtualenv before i execute my code using shell script.

Here is the shell file `runshell.sh` , but it doesn't start the virtual enviorment.

```
source /var/www/abc/python/bin/activate
python /var/www/abc/code/app.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as you do in shell

```
#!/bin/bash
source /var/www/abc/python/bin/activate
python /var/www/abc/code/app.py
```

Or you can directly run python from venv

```
#!/bin/bash
/var/www/abc/python/bin/python /var/www/abc/code/app.py
```

Comment: What make it does not work? Any error or something else?

Comment: it doesn't start the virtualenv , becuase it gives me an error of the plugins which is already installed in virtualenv